VPS Ubuntu 22.04 - Django - Gunicorn - Nginx
If I use; gunicorn --bind 0.0.0.0:8000 my_project.wsgi works
Then this is my config:
gunicorn.socket

[Unit]

Description=gunicorn socket

[Socket]

ListenStream=/run/gunicorn.sock

[Install]

WantedBy=sockets.target

gunicorn service

[Unit]

Description=gunicorn daemon

Requires=gunicorn.socket

After=network.target

[Service]

User=my_user

Group=www-data

WorkingDirectory=/home/my_user/test 

EnvironmentFile=/home/my_user/test/.env

ExecStart=/home/my_user/test/env/bin/gunicorn \

--access-logfile - \

--workers 3 \

--bind unix:/run/gunicorn.sock \

my_project.wsgi:application

[Install]

WantedBy=multi-user.target

/etc/nginx/sites-available/test

server {

    listen 80;

    server_name IP;

    location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; 
}

location /static/ {

    root /home/my_user/test;

}

location / {

    include proxy_params;

    proxy_pass http://unix:/run/gunicorn.sock;

    proxy_set_header Host $host;

    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;

    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;

    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;

}

}

Every systemctl status is running but I still show Welcome to Nginx! I want to show my Django App. What can i do?

Did you delete the default file in the sites-enabled directory of nginx?
